# does selenium knows to analyse the browser activity log or network activity?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to verify an ajax call was triggered

and also I want to detect a call to external custom protocol was triggered.

I think I will be able to read that data in this way only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Selenium is not meant for such use case. Selenium WebDriver is just meant for simulating user interactions with web app. If you want intercept network requests, add custom headers etc during your selenium tests, you can use a proxy. [BrowserMob proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) is popular for such use cases with selenium tests. It has a REST API too.